# How many lines are needed to create 6 triangles on W?

Tags: geometry

Basically, the question started with a little argument I had with my friend. My friend said he thinks it's possible to draw only 2 lines on the letter "W" and make 6 triangles, and I played around with it, but I couldn't really do it, so I told him I don't think it's possible, and we need at least 3 lines.

We kept arguing, but I really couldn't prove that we need more than 2 lines on letter "W" to create 6 triangles except that I couldn't find a way of doing so. 
Is there any proof for this kind of problem?

PS. Sorry. I didn't clarify. You CANNOT combine one or more triangles to form a triangle and count that separately. Triangles must be INTERNALLY disjoint.
For instance, if triangles ABC, BCD can be combined to form triangle ADC, then we don't count ADC as a triangle.

Comment: Can the triangles overlap? May their interiors contain a line segment? If so, you can actually create 8 triangles with two lines.

Comment: Alright I'm starting to believe it's impossible as well, though I'm not sure what math structure to hang the picture on. Graphs? A clever application of Euler's formula may help you...

Answer (score 1):

No one said the W couldn't be "cursive"...

[image]
Perhaps not what the OP was looking for (and I'm aware this post was brought back from YEARS AGO, but I just thought I'd share this) but this solution does contain $6$ triangles with only $2$ lines

Answer (score 0):

It only takes two lines to get six triangles? Let me try to add a picture real quick.[image: j]

So far the max I can find with two lines is $5$. Ill keep trying!

Comment: I don't think OP counts $BCF$ or $ACD$

Comment: I'd assume the intent is for internally disjoint triangles: so I count only 4.

Comment: What if I moved $\overline {CD}$ and made it $\overline {CD'}$ where $D'$ was on $\overline {AD}$? Would that help?

Comment: @Fmonkey2001: I still count 4.

Comment: Why doesn't the intersection of $HC$ and $BE$ count as a vertex? I mean, with that one, we do have five triangles (if we call the point $I$, $IBF$ and  $IFG$ are two triangles).

Comment: Move AF a bit up and we are done

Answer (score 0):

Consider this two lines / but a bit more inclined and one intersecting each other. Now the point where they cross has to be in one of the central side in W. Sorry for no having a picture.

Answer (score -1):

Three parallel lines one at the top, one middle, one bottom, and, if tri inside tri is allowed, you have $6$. Of these, $3$ are true and $3$ more are built around their respective parent.